# node.js node-http-proxy not receiving trailers

Tags: node.js, node-http-proxy

I'm adding a trailer to a response in Node and I just can't seem to get the trailer to be received as part of the message. I want to use it to send timing information back to a load balancer I've written in Node, so it can monitor if requests are queuing for a long time in a particular worker.

I'm trying with just a basic app to get it working first, which I've taken from the documentation for [addTrailers](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/http.html#http_response_addtrailers_headers):

```
var http = require("http");

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
     var fileData = "Hello World!";
     res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
     'Trailer': 'my-trailer' });
     res.write(fileData);
     res.write("\r\n");
     res.addTrailers({'my-trailer': 'test'});
     res.end();
});
server.listen(12345);
```

I'm using node-http-proxy in the load balancer and it doesn't receive the trailers, Charles Proxy doesn't show them and neither does curl 7.35.  However, wireshark does show the data at the end of the packet:

```
c
Hello World!
2


0
my-trailer: test
```

Does anyone know what you have to do to get Node to parse a trailer from a message rather than discard it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having investigated quite deeply, trailers aren't set until `http.ClientRequest` emits the `end` event (which makes sense, I guess).  This isn't documented on [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy#listening-for-proxy-events) but looking at the code it is emitted.

So we can set up a handler for the `end` event

```
proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();
proxy.on("end", function(req, res, proxyRes){
    console.log(proxyRes.trailers);
});
proxy.listen(8000);
```

and my trailer is there!

```
{ 'x-worker-duration': '7.397' }
```

Comment: For anyone else running into this issue - the `Trailer` header is only valid for chunked encoding - it should not work in any other case. The issues and hack applied above, is _most likely_ due to the fact that the response was not chunked encoded.